# Uploading file into Google Cloud Mobile Backend

Tags: android, backend, google-cloud-datastore

I was testing and studying the code from Google Mobile Backend Starter demo application for android and found out that it is using the Google Cloud Datastore, which I dont really understand how it works as I have no decent experience in dealing with storage and database.
The question is:

1) Can Google Cloud Datastore store files?

2) If it can, how to do so from android app POV?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can serialize the file and then store it in the datastore, but this is not what it is meant to do. The Datastore is basically a database and is meant to store information not files.

Comment: If I am to store merely data, let's say I am going to store x and y in the same row within the datastore, is it possible? NoSQL is really confusing for a database-newbie like me.

Comment: Kind of, more like x is the identifier for y, but it is actually quite easy, if you want it even simpler you can use a library like https://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/

Comment: App Engine datastore and Google Cloud Datastore are the same thing?

Comment: well app engine uses google cloud datastore. So you can choose to either use app engine to access datastore which offloads some of the work from the device or you can directly use the datastore, which may be more expensive, but probably simpler, for a similar tutorial look here: https://developers.google.com/datastore/docs/getstarted/start_java/